# Android Studio emulator Symbol not found: _pwritev

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After last update of Android emulator I can not start any virtual device. Even if I create a new one. The emulator is shown for a few second and then I get an error and the macOS shows in the problem report:

qemu-system-x86_64 quit unexpectedly

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _pwritev
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Android/*/qemu-system-x86_64
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Invalidate cash and restart doesn't help.

Comment: this is an related issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191799887

Answer (score 3):

Ok, thanks to `Usama Altaf` the problem is described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191805460). The Problem occurs on macOS Catalina with the emulator version 30.7.4.
There are two possible solutions:

1. Update the macOS to Big Sur.
2. Downgrade the emulator version.

If you want to downgrade the emulator:

- Close Android Studio
- Download and unzip an older version provided [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin_x64-7140946.zip)
- Replace files in $ANDROID_HOME/emulator
- Launch Android Studio and it will use the new files

Comment: You can just uninstall the Emulator from Android Studio SDK Tools. You will then see version 30.6.5 available to install. The Android team probably removed 30.7.4.

Comment: now 30.9.5 is available ..